# SQL query question

Tags: sql

So...I'm new to sql and loving what I've learned, but here is a question I'm stumped on.

I've created a website form. It's a timecard type form. A user logs on and clicks a pull down menu (which is being selected from the DB) It's called `jobsite`, then he scrolls down and clicks Jobsite#2. (both fields are selecting from the same table..) When they submit, it submits into the DB just fine. Showing both fields as the ID number they picked.. Not the name..

```
SELECT  jobsite.Jobsite as 'Customer',
FROM    timeCard
LEFT JOIN jobsite ON timeCard.jobsite = jobsite.id
```

That query works great. Pulling `timeCard.jobsite` information. If I change it to

```
LEFT JOIN jobsite ON timeCard.jobsite2 = jobsite.id
```

That works great too pulling all the inputted data from Jobsite2...What query will work to get them to show as 'Customer 1, and Customer2' on the same query? Does my question make sense? I'm trying to get it to export into Excel so that it would show up with all the information on one line basically. Employee 1, worked at jobsite 1 and jobsite 4 (but instead show: Employee (me) worked at (this place) and (that place)

Where both jobsites come from the same table in the DB

Thanks for any help you guys/gals can give

Answer (score 4):

You're going to need to join to the `jobsite` table twice, because one `timecard` record is associated with two different `jobsite` records (assuming some things about your schema and DBMS...):

```
SELECT t.EmployeeName, j1.jobsite AS 'Customer 1', j2.jobsite AS 'Customer 2'
FROM timecard t
LEFT JOIN jobsite j1 ON t.jobsite = j1.id
LEFT JOIN jobsite j2 ON t.jobsite2 = j2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  js1.jobsite AS customer1, js2.jobsite AS customer2
FROM    timecard tc
LEFT JOIN
        jobsite js1
ON      js1.id = tc.jobsite
LEFT JOIN
        jobsite js2
ON      js2.id = tc.jobsite2
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for something like this?

```
SELECT jobsite.Jobsite as 'Customer',
FROM   timeCard, jobSite
WHERE  timeCard.jobsite = jobsite.id
 OR timeCard.jobsite2 = jobsite.id
```

(PS. Since you mentioned you are new to SQL, I'd like to take this opportunity to make sure you know about parameterized queries (articles on [ASP.Net](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/10/24/2528.aspx), [PHP](http://mattbango.com/notebook/web-development/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/)), which you should *always* be using instead of concatenating strings)